# Problem with Doctrine_Expression (Doctrine 2) 'There is no open connection'

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have Doctrine2 working fine with my Zend PHP stack.

However if I want to use [Doctrine_Expression](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_expression.html),

```
$item->setDateCreated(new Doctrine_Expression('NOW()'));
```

then I get following error **'There is no open connection'**. 
This is stack trace:

```
#0 D:\data\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\Doctrine\Manager.php(264): Doctrine_Manager->getCurrentConnection()
#1 D:\data\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\Doctrine\Expression.php(72): Doctrine_Manager::connection()
#2 D:\data\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\Doctrine\Expression.php(116): Doctrine_Expression->getConnection()
#3 D:\data\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\Doctrine\Expression.php(133): Doctrine_Expression->parseExpression('NOW()')
#4 D:\data\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\Doctrine\Expression.php(89): Doctrine_Expression->parseClause('NOW()')
#5 D:\data\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\Doctrine\Expression.php(60): Doctrine_Expression->setExpression('NOW()')
#6 D:\data\work\gazette\Projects\NorskTipping\admin-system\code\application\library\MagicHeads\Knalledge\Models\Tagging.php(91): Doctrine_Expression->__construct('NOW()')
...
#14 {main}
```

I tried to add connection

```
$item->setDateCreated(new Doctrine_Expression('NOW()', $this->_em->getConnection()));
```

However, it happens it is connection of type [Doctrine\DBAL\Connection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/doctrine/dbal/connection.html) while Doctrine_Expression requires [Doctrine_Connection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_connection.html)

How I can get Doctrine_Connection and provide it to Doctrine_Expression?

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine_Expression is a Doctrine 1 class and can not be used with Doctrine 2. The two versions are very different and not compatible.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get it working with Doctrine 2?
How I can introduce some MySQL function (like NOW()) into my DQL?
I.e. what is replacement for 
$item->setDateCreated(new Doctrine_Expression('NOW()'));
in Doctrine 2 DQL

Comment: In Doctrine 2 you would just do this in your object with a PHP DateTime: $item->setDateCreated(new \DateTime('now'));

Comment: OK, thanks, I knew that, but again, that doesn't help with passing other SQL expressions. We still need Doctrine_Expression, and it does exist. It is not obsolated in Doctrine 2 :)
There is still need for 
...
new Doctrine_Expression('DATE_ADD(a.b, INTERVAL a.c HOUR)')